# Mysql - Procedimiento almacenado no calcula bien si existe la persona

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-procedimiento

me he creado este procedimiento almacenado:

```
create
    definer = miUsuario@miHost procedure guardar(IN name varchar(200), IN surname_1 varchar(200),
                                               IN surname_2 varchar(200), IN birthday date)
begin
    -- COMPRUEBO SI YA EXISTE UN USUARIO CON ESOS DATOS, SI EXISTE LE PONGO EL FLAG 'IS_NEW' A FALSE
    -- ... Y SI NO A TRUE
    set @isNew := 0;
    set @inDB := (select  exists(select *
               from persons
               where name= name and surname_1 = surname_1 and surname_2 = surname_2 and birthday = birthday
               limit 1));

    if @inDB = 0 then
      set @isNew := 1;
    end if;


-- INSERTO LA PERSONA CON EL FLAG 'IS_NEW' YA CALCULADO PREVIAMENTE EN EL PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO
insert into persons(name, surname_1, surname_2, birthday, created_at, updated_at,is_new)
    values(name, surname_1, surname_2, birthday, current_timestamp, current_timestamp, @isNew);
end;
```

La funcionalidad es muy simple, en  cada registro de personas tiene un campo llamado `is_new` con el que compruebo si es la primera vez que se inserta un usuario con ese conjunto de datos  (`name`,`surname_1`, `surname_2`,`birthday`).

Es decir, si no existe ninguno insertara la filo con `is_new` a `1`,
a partir de ese deberia de almacenar todos los que coincidan con el flag `is_new` a `0`

El problema es que la comprobacion previa que hago para ello **no esta funcionando**, y cuando lo pruebo de **forma aislada si funciona**.

Comment: ***¿Cuál es tu versión de MySQL?***, ***¿Dónde esta los DELIMITER?***

Comment: La primera cosa que veo mal en tu código es que no necesitas esto para saber si la persona existe: `select  exists(select * ...)`, es mucho mejor una consulta simple del tipo `select count(*) from persons where ...` y no hace falta que pongas `limit 1` tampoco. Tampoco entiendo a qué te refieres con *comprobacion previa* ¿? No está explicado claramente el contexto en tu pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano muy buena observación, ademas luego puede añadir ``IF (0>var) THEN SELECT 'no existe'; ELSE SELECT 'Existe'; END IF;`` de tal manera que la consulta la meta en un ``SELECT count(*) INTO var FROM tutabla`` para luego realizar lo que deseas y por supuesto declarar antes la variable con ``DECLARE var INT DEFAULT 0;`` de esta manera es como suelo comprobar si existe.

Comment: @JavierG.Raya creo que falta contexto. Es decir, no entiendo cuál es el propósito de su procedure. Lo lógico es usar este tipo de cosas para verificar antes de insertar, o para decidir si se inserta, se actualiza, se borra, etc. OP no explica nada del contexto y eso no ayuda a una respuesta clara o a sugerirle mejores prácticas.

Comment: te doy la razón este tipo de cosas se usan sobre todo para los trigger, lo que si se suele usar mucho es realizar una función primero y luego esa función llamarla en el trigger @A.Cedano

Comment: Cambia el nombre de los parámetros, ej. `name` a `pName`. Cuando en la consulta pones `name` MySQL no sabe si te refieres a la columna o al parámetro.

Comment: Yo haría un trigger, con eso podría cambiar lo que ya está ANTES de insertar y no terminar actualizando todo por igual.